# Physical interpretation of scalar tadpole loops

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

In Feynman diagrams, fermionic loops are drawn like this:

[image]

While scalar loops are drawn as tadpoles:

[image]

I assume the difference comes from the scalar not having an anti-particle. But how should one imagine such a tadpole diagram? I can imagine the fermionic loop as creation of particle and antiparticle, but I am at loss to only get a faint idea what the scalar loop should illustrate.

Comment: You should learn how the feynman diagrams are drawn with a given lagrangian, the answer is there.